# How to solve simg2img error "Invalid sparse file format at header magi"?

Tags: extract

I installed android-tools-fsutils using the terminal on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ran simg2img to extract RemixOS's system.img file but each time I get the same error - "Invalid sparse file format at header magi."

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I figured out what the problem was. Turns out simg2img converts system.img to raw img, but RemixOS's system.img is already a raw image. So, I just had to mount the image as a loop device.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)